# RatingBar with pink background when holding

Tags: android, android-studio, ratingbar

My RatingBar is pretty regular, when selected appears like this[image]

But when touching (and holding) them, all unrated stars are pink, like this

[image]

Why does this happen?

The xml:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBarSchedulesRatingTour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressTint="@color/yellow_star"
    android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/yellow_star"
    android:stepSize="1" />
```

@color/yellow_star is on colors.xml as #F1CD1E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:progressBackgroundTint` attribute on `RatingBar` to override background color:

```
android:progressBackgroundTint="#ABABAB"
```

Comment: Do you know what is the default background color of the rating bar?

Answer (score 1):

Create Style and color what you want (press/normal)

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#F1CD1E</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#F1CD1E</item>
    </style>

<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBarSchedulesRatingTour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:progressTint="#F1CD1E"
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="#F1CD1E"
        android:stepSize="1" />
```

Comment: This does help cleaning the code by not needing to use "progressTint" and "secondaryProgressTint", but it doesn't change the background color of unselected stars